# Updating A React Array State

Tags: reactjs, react-state

I have a react app which fetches questions from a django api into the state.
The problem i am facing now is, updating a specific question's title since the title input element takes it value from the state.

## Below Is How My State Looks Like

```
const [testQuestionForm, setTestQuestionForm] = useState({
        show: true,
        questions: [
            {
                showCover: true,
                id: 1, title: "", answer: {
                    type: "", responses: [
                        { id: 1, response: "first" },
                        { id: 2, response: "second" }, 
                        { id: 3, response: "third" }, 
                        { id: 4, response: "fourth" }]
                }
            },
            { id: 2, title: "", answer: { type: "", responses: [{ id: 1, response: "null" }] } }
        ]
    })
```

Before Reaching The Stage In My Program Where I Had To Update The Title,
Incase the user wanted to add an answer or delete an answer or do any action which has to trigger the manipulation of the state, i used the logic below

## Below Is A Code Sample Which Updates The Type Of Answer A User Would Want The Question To Have

The Steps Are

1. I get the question id from the event's target.
2. I store the state's questions in a local variable
   // I do this for easier manipulation since i don't know any better way to do this
3. I filter the values of the variable for the first question with the id
4. I do the changes i want then i update the state again by replacing all values

```
 const setQuestionAnswerType = (event) => {
        const questionId = parseInt(event.target.dataset['questionid']);
        const questionValue = event.target.value;
        const allStateQuestions = testQuestionForm.questions;
        const currentStateQuestion = allStateQuestions.filter(question => question.id === questionId)[0];
        currentStateQuestion.answer.type = questionValue;
        setTestQuestionForm({ ...testQuestionForm, questions: allStateQuestions });

    }
```

All seemed to be working fine until i had to update the question's title.
The Above Steps did not work for me so i tried another way.

## Below Is The New Logic I Tried To Update The Question's Title

```
  const updateTitle = (event) => {
        const question = testQuestionForm.questions.filter(question => question.id === event.target.id)[0];
        setTestQuestionForm({ ...testQuestionForm, questions: [...testQuestionForm.questions, { ...testQuestionForm.questions.question, title: event.target.value }] })
    }
```

Any time i do it this way, the browser renders a blank page and a lot of errors are thrown in the console by react.

## Below Is A Traceback Of The Error

```
TypeError: question.answer is undefined
QuestionComponent
src/Test/components/createTestComponents.js:7

   4 | 
   5 | const QuestionComponent = (props) => {
   6 |     var { question, setTestQuestionForm, testQuestionForm, function2 } = props
>  7 |     var { id, title, answer: { type }, showCover } = question;
   8 |     const updateTitle = (event) => {
   9 |         const question = testQuestionForm.questions.filter(question => question.id === event.target.id)[0];
  10 |         

This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.
```

I think it's because question.answer is an array so i will have to do the changes in a loop or using the respective high order array method but i don't know how to do it in the
`setTestQuestionForm({})` function.

If the question above does not make sense enough please let me know.

Comment: `event.target.id` is a string, and won't match `question.id === event.target.id`, thus your `filter` inside `updateTitle` will be an empty array and because you ask for the first item of an empty array, question gets `undefined` assigned

Comment: please check well.
I converted it into an integer before doing the filtering.

Comment: But I am talking about the new logic for updating the title, not the old one :) then again that one doesn't even seem to use the `question`. The question in itself is a bit of a jumble, so I find it hard to read anything else but the code (referring to the h1 and the needless repeated uppercasing of single words in a sentence) . From the error, I would say, your question doesn't have an answer defined. However, you do not show where you actually render your `QuestionComponent`

Comment: okay. I will rearrange my state and update my question to reflect your proposal